# Rewriting controller vs. adding a new controller to an existing module

Tags: module, magento-1, controllers, third-party-module

I'm looking at a community extension called Ambassador_Affiliate, and it's doing something that I have not seen before. I'm not sure what it's doing, so I'd like to check with the community.

In `config.xml`, there is...

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <customer>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Ambassador_Affiliate before="Mage_Customer">Ambassador_Affiliate</Ambassador_Affiliate>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </customer>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

In `Ambassador/Affiliate/controllers/AffiliateController.php`, there is…

```
<?php

class Ambassador_Affiliate_AffiliateController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
…


}
```

It looks to me the Ambassador extension is adding a new controller, instead of rewriting, its own controller to the `Mage_Customer` module.

If it is so, why would you do this as opposed to just defining a entirely new controller under `Ambassador_Affiliate` (beside wanting to use the `customer` frontname of `Mage_Customer`)?

If it's not, what is it doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento checks all `controllers` whether the `actionMethod` exists, if this is the case, then it is executed.

The sorting order, can be defined via `before` and `after`

But using after makes no sense, if you ask me. If you want your controller to be executed, instead of the default one use `before`.

So if you want to kill all other actions, you can use your own `frontName` (with uppercase N!), if you only want to add one action, this is the right way.

Comment: How about `Ambassador_Affiliate_AffiliateController`? Why isn't it just being defined as a new controller in `config.xml`?

Comment: When you mean by a new controller a new route, like `ambassador/controllername/actionname`, then because the developer prefered to put it into the `customer/*` "namespace"

Comment: OK just to confirm, by defining it in the `config.xml` like above (`<frontend><routers><customer><args><modules>`) and not rewriting an existing controller), it will use `customer/.../...`?

Comment: Yes, when you use frontend/routers/... it will use customer. But what do you mean by rewrite exactly? There is no controller rewrite as for models, helpers and classes...

Comment: Typically when people use `<frontend><routers>…`, they end up creating a controller that extends an existing controller (i.e. "rewrite/override" by `Abc_Xyz_Checkout_CartController extends Mage_Core_Checkout_CartController`). I just meant that this particular extension is not doing that.

Comment: Ah, ok got it. If you extend the Mage_Customer Controller then everything ends in your controller, because all the action methods are present. Doing this or not doing this is (as always) a matter of do you need the inheritance or not. If there are protected methods you want to use, inherit if not, then not - I would say.